# Polars apply return only null after second row

Tags: python, dataframe, python-polars

I'm trying to apply a custom function to each row of the dataframe. The function itself returns a dataframe with more columns and rows. To obtain one big dataframe I use `explode()` in the end.

The first `apply()` is performed succesfully. But after that it only returns `null`. When debugging you can see that the actual dataframe is returned in the function but it still ends up as a row of nulls.

Any ideas on how to resolve this?

**Current result:**

```
Polars
 shape: (9, 2)
┌───────────┬───────────┐
│ column_0  ┆ column_1  │
│ ---       ┆ ---       │
│ f64       ┆ f64       │
╞═══════════╪═══════════╡
│ 23.92626  ┆ 22.921899 │
│ 2.099872  ┆ 17.662035 │
│ 20.393656 ┆ 5.777625  │
│ 14.643948 ┆ 4.797752  │
│ ...       ┆ ...       │
│ null      ┆ null      │
│ null      ┆ null      │
│ null      ┆ null      │
│ null      ┆ null      │
└───────────┴───────────┘
```

**Code:**

```
import polars as pl
import numpy as np

def myfunc(x):
    data1 = np.random.uniform(low=0, high=25, size=(5,))
    data2 = np.random.uniform(low=0, high=25, size=(5,))

    # Just a example dataframe to show
    df = pl.DataFrame([data1, data2])
    
    return df

df = pl.DataFrame({
    'val1': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
    'val2': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
})

output = df.apply(myfunc)
output = output.explode(output.columns)

print('\nPolars\n',output)
```

Comment: It looks like that would be equivalent to: `output = pl.concat(myfunc(row) for row in df.iter_rows())` - perhaps there's a better way of doing things than going row-by-row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Brener Ramos thanks for your answer! It is indeed not necessary to create the dataframe inside `myfunc`. I just want to add here that if you want to return more than a few values here you can pass them as a tuple:

**Code:**

```
import polars as pl
import numpy as np

def myfunc(x):
    data = np.random.random((24,25))

    return tuple(data.tolist())

df = pl.DataFrame({
    'val1': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
    'val2': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
})

output = df.apply(myfunc)
output = output.explode(output.columns)

print('\nPolars\n',output)
```

**Output:**

```
┌──────────┬──────────┬──────────┬──────────┬─────┬───────────┬───────────┬───────────┬───────────┐
│ column_0 ┆ column_1 ┆ column_2 ┆ column_3 ┆ ... ┆ column_20 ┆ column_21 ┆ column_22 ┆ column_23 │
│ ---      ┆ ---      ┆ ---      ┆ ---      ┆     ┆ ---       ┆ ---       ┆ ---       ┆ ---       │
│ f64      ┆ f64      ┆ f64      ┆ f64      ┆     ┆ f64       ┆ f64       ┆ f64       ┆ f64       │
╞══════════╪══════════╪══════════╪══════════╪═════╪═══════════╪═══════════╪═══════════╪═══════════╡
│ 0.27537  ┆ 0.709138 ┆ 0.546163 ┆ 0.395388 ┆ ... ┆ 0.060717  ┆ 0.400735  ┆ 0.070704  ┆ 0.568049  │
│ 0.261544 ┆ 0.79145  ┆ 0.01426  ┆ 0.36353  ┆ ... ┆ 0.851114  ┆ 0.229688  ┆ 0.300372  ┆ 0.808558  │
│ 0.323391 ┆ 0.574013 ┆ 0.426368 ┆ 0.414267 ┆ ... ┆ 0.054039  ┆ 0.256431  ┆ 0.070362  ┆ 0.36685   │
│ 0.018229 ┆ 0.933077 ┆ 0.791328 ┆ 0.597989 ┆ ... ┆ 0.890257  ┆ 0.145317  ┆ 0.550311  ┆ 0.931699  │
│ ...      ┆ ...      ┆ ...      ┆ ...      ┆ ... ┆ ...       ┆ ...       ┆ ...       ┆ ...       │
│ 0.638956 ┆ 0.074074 ┆ 0.189303 ┆ 0.315919 ┆ ... ┆ 0.516329  ┆ 0.515838  ┆ 0.703168  ┆ 0.583693  │
│ 0.123835 ┆ 0.0947   ┆ 0.62298  ┆ 0.078458 ┆ ... ┆ 0.676711  ┆ 0.446069  ┆ 0.984048  ┆ 0.594556  │
│ 0.046898 ┆ 0.276947 ┆ 0.840632 ┆ 0.174021 ┆ ... ┆ 0.206967  ┆ 0.78914   ┆ 0.215281  ┆ 0.98951   │
│ 0.056735 ┆ 0.004694 ┆ 0.564832 ┆ 0.058331 ┆ ... ┆ 0.861793  ┆ 0.598087  ┆ 0.636651  ┆ 0.692745  │
└──────────┴──────────┴──────────┴──────────┴─────┴───────────┴───────────┴───────────┴───────────┘
```

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to create the dataframe inside `myfunc`. Just return the values in a list.

```py
import polars as pl
import numpy as np

def myfunc(x):
    data1 = np.random.uniform(low=0, high=25, size=(5,))
    data2 = np.random.uniform(low=0, high=25, size=(5,))    
    return data1.tolist(), data2.tolist()

df = pl.DataFrame({
    'val1': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
    'val2': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
})

output = df.apply(myfunc)
output = output.explode(output.columns)

print('\nPolars\n',output)
```